# AT+COPS=? return operation not allowed

Tags: android, at-command, modem

i am trying to receive  the nearby cell information from  using my device which is qualcomm snapdragon msm8909. the device has 6 modems which i can control using gpio's.

i should note that no sim is inserted into the device, therefore i have no intention of connecting to any particular cell, only extract the relevant information about them.

when i invoke at+creg? i get CREG:0,0 returned, which is not connected and not searching.
 then when i want to list the operators i invoke at+cops=? the response after a few seconds is :
+CME ERROR: operation not allowed.

does anyone know why this is happening and how can i change it?

thank you.

Comment: Can you share the output of AT+COPS? Network scan is not allowed if the device is in the mode 2 (i.e. deregister from network). Try to set manual mode by AT+COPS=1 (AT+COPS=0 requires a SIM card) and re-run network scan AT+COPS=?

Comment: hey, thank you for tour comment. when i try COPS=1  i receive an ERROR message with no output. do you have any idea why this could be happening? thank you. when i try AT+COPS? the output is +COPS:1

Comment: edit: i found the problem with my device. it had to do with specific gpio configuration. thank you for the help.

Comment: You got an error because of missing arguments AT+COPS=[<mode>[,<format>[,<oper>[,<AcT>]]]] or due to missing SIM card. The idea was to force manual mode. Did it work?